# How to modify CONFIG_CPU_TYPE in .config

Tags: openwrt

I'm building OpenWrt from source to run in QEMU for a research project. I want to use an x86-64 build since it will be a little easier for my purposes. when I go through the process of downloading and building all is successful except it won't run in qemu as the default CPU type is "pentium4".

As I understand OpenWrt the build configuration is stored in .config. The .config file is created/modified one of three ways:

make menuconfig
make kernel_config
make defconfig

I've used the search option in menuconfig and kernel_config and I see no setting for CONFIG_CPU_TYPE. I manually changed the setting as well as the associated options and get a successful build with target_i386_i486_musl.

I'd rather not modify .config directly if I don't have to. What is the correct way to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Manually changing/adding parameter in .config won't help, as those parameters are not defined in the framework.
If you want to build it from the source then may be start by selecting

```
Target System (x86)
Subtarget (x86_64)
Target Profile (Generic)
```

in make menuconfig. OR
You can directly download the x86 image and use it([external links](https://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/doc/openwrt_x86)).